# LDAP over TLS fails to connect, Schannel Alert 48

Tags: active-directory, php, ldap, tls, certificate-authority

I am trying to use PHP to edit users in active directory through LDAP.
My test machine is using a simple WAMP setup and is NOT connected to the windows domain. This machine can connect to LDAP on the Domain Controller just fine without encryption. I could not get it to connect via SSL after repeated attempts but I was able to get it to use TLS (ldap_start_tls) which enables me to change user password, which is the ultimate goal. No issues there on the test box.

The actual web server though IS a member of the domain and it refuses to work. The connection fails with TLS and the Domain Controller reports an schannel fatal alert 48 which means there is an untrusted root CA in the cert chain. I have installed the cert on the web server and installed the root CA cert on both the web server and DC to no avail. I'm not sure where to go from here.

What am I doing wrong? Why would LDAP over TLS work fine on a computer outside the domain but not on one that's part of the domain?

Lately I've been comparing the certs and chains on all 3 machines. The only difference I've found is the chain on both the working (non-domain) web server and the DC is three steps: COMODO -> COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA -> My cert
The web server on the domain is the same except everything is moved down a level and the top level cert says "USER Trust"

Is this difference causing the issue?

verify command on original cert file on non-working webserver:
Issuer:

```
    CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
    O=COMODO CA Limited
    L=Salford
    S=Greater Manchester
    C=GB
Subject:
    CN=cjtrainor.com
    OU=COMODO SSL Unified Communications
    OU=Domain Control Validated
Cert Serial Number: bd4d0f693ab0104ac9f1b45003d6138d

dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_CONSOLE_TRACE (0x20000000)
dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_DUMP_CHAIN (0x40000000)
ChainFlags = CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT (0x40000000)
HCCE_LOCAL_MACHINE
CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_BASE
-------- CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT --------
ChainContext.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
ChainContext.dwRevocationFreshnessTime: 3 Days, 16 Hours, 4 Minutes, 14 Seconds

SimpleChain.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
SimpleChain.dwRevocationFreshnessTime: 3 Days, 16 Hours, 4 Minutes, 14 Seconds

CertContext[0][0]: dwInfoStatus=102 dwErrorStatus=0
  Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, O=COMODO CA Limited,
 L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  NotBefore: 6/8/2015 8:00 PM
  NotAfter: 11/1/2015 7:59 PM
  Subject: CN=cjtrainor.com, OU=COMODO SSL Unified Communications, OU=Domain Con
trol Validated
  Serial: bd4d0f693ab0104ac9f1b45003d6138d
  SubjectAltName: DNS Name=cjtrainor.com, DNS Name=NewServer.cjtrainor.local, DN
S Name=cjtrainor.local
  41 fb 61 2e db f5 76 49 05 1e a9 73 66 cc 10 4a 71 6c 9a 15
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_KEY_MATCH_ISSUER (0x2)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
    CRL (null):
    Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, O=COMODO CA Limite
d, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
    61 3b b6 5c 6f df 50 e7 9f 64 21 09 ab 11 8a f5 bc 11 5f 6c
  Issuance[0] = 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.7
  Issuance[1] = 2.23.140.1.2.1
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication

CertContext[0][1]: dwInfoStatus=102 dwErrorStatus=0
  Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford,
 S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  NotBefore: 2/11/2014 8:00 PM
  NotAfter: 2/11/2029 7:59 PM
  Subject: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, O=COMODO CA Limited
, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Serial: 2b2e6eead975366c148a6edba37c8c07
  33 9c dd 57 cf d5 b1 41 16 9b 61 5f f3 14 28 78 2d 1d a6 39
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_KEY_MATCH_ISSUER (0x2)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
    CRL (null):
    Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salfor
d, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
    ca e2 4c d2 71 15 63 f3 a9 0f 6a fb 8c 60 7f 73 6b b9 b6 79
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication

CertContext[0][2]: dwInfoStatus=10c dwErrorStatus=0
  Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford,
 S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  NotBefore: 1/18/2010 8:00 PM
  NotAfter: 1/18/2038 7:59 PM
  Subject: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford
, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Serial: 4caaf9cadb636fe01ff74ed85b03869d
  af e5 d2 44 a8 d1 19 42 30 ff 47 9f e2 f8 97 bb cd 7a 8c b4
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_NAME_MATCH_ISSUER (0x4)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_SELF_SIGNED (0x8)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication
  Application[2] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4 Secure Email
  Application[3] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 Code Signing
  Application[4] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8 Time Stamping
  Application[5] = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4 Encrypting File System
  Application[6] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.6 IP security tunnel termination
  Application[7] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.7 IP security user

Exclude leaf cert:
  80 98 de 5e 8f 00 8a b8 19 21 23 cd 96 bd f4 ae a8 5c 9e cc
Full chain:
  9c 7b 73 21 92 d4 b7 70 36 52 f5 e8 9f cb 16 25 a6 6a b9 77
------------------------------------
Verified Issuance Policies:
    1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.7
    2.23.140.1.2.1
Verified Application Policies:
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication
Cert is an End Entity certificate
Leaf certificate revocation check passed
CertUtil: -verify command completed successfully.
```

verify command on the working webserver:

```
Issuer:
    CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server
    O=COMODO CA Limited
    L=Salford
    S=Greater Manchester
    C=GB
  Name Hash(sha1): 7ae13ee8a0c42a2cb428cbe7a605461
  Name Hash(md5): 737301010f9ec759d54329bbb1553aa2
Subject:
    CN=cjtrainor.com
    OU=COMODO SSL Unified Communications
    OU=Domain Control Validated
  Name Hash(sha1): d75889ccf0886cb2b6873fedbdcf079
  Name Hash(md5): a584a7d4ec9fb308a698d4921379f5bd
Cert Serial Number: bd4d0f693ab0104ac9f1b45003d613

dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_CONSOLE_TRACE (0x2000000
dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_DUMP_CHAIN (0x40000000)
ChainFlags = CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXC
HCCE_LOCAL_MACHINE
CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_BASE
-------- CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT --------
ChainContext.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERR
ChainContext.dwRevocationFreshnessTime: 19 Hours,

SimpleChain.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRE
SimpleChain.dwRevocationFreshnessTime: 19 Hours, 1

CertContext[0][0]: dwInfoStatus=102 dwErrorStatus=
  Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure S
 L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  NotBefore: 6/8/2015 8:00 PM
  NotAfter: 11/1/2015 7:59 PM
  Subject: CN=cjtrainor.com, OU=COMODO SSL Unified
trol Validated
  Serial: bd4d0f693ab0104ac9f1b45003d6138d
  SubjectAltName: DNS Name=cjtrainor.com, DNS Name
S Name=cjtrainor.local
  159a6c714a10cc6673a91e054976f5db2e61fb41
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_KEY_MATCH_
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_
    CRL (null):
    Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure
d, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
    ThisUpdate: 7/8/2015 8:26 PM
    NextUpdate: 7/12/2015 8:26 PM
    bf512c78f12e36d6fd4b8d7430d38b516c49368c
  Issuance[0] = 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.7
  Issuance[1] = 2.23.140.1.2.1
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authen
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authen

CertContext[0][1]: dwInfoStatus=102 dwErrorStatus=
  Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O
 S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  NotBefore: 2/11/2014 8:00 PM
  NotAfter: 2/11/2029 7:59 PM
  Subject: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure
, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Serial: 2b2e6eead975366c148a6edba37c8c07
  39a61d2d782814f35f619b1641b1d5cf57dd9c33
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_KEY_MATCH_
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_
    CRL (null):
    Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority,
d, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
    ThisUpdate: 7/8/2015 10:49 PM
    NextUpdate: 7/12/2015 10:49 PM
    291aa1576538dd0005d5daf2bfc9c9695ad3d668
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authen
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authen

CertContext[0][2]: dwInfoStatus=10c dwErrorStatus=
  Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O
 S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  NotBefore: 1/18/2010 8:00 PM
  NotAfter: 1/18/2038 7:59 PM
  Subject: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority,
, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Serial: 4caaf9cadb636fe01ff74ed85b03869d
  b48c7acdbb97f8e29f47ff304219d1a844d2e5af
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_NAME_MATCH
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_SELF_SIGNED
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authen
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authen
  Application[2] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4 Secure Email
  Application[3] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 Code Signing
  Application[4] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8 Time Stamping
  Application[5] = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4 Encrypti
  Application[6] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.6 IP security t
  Application[7] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.7 IP security u

Exclude leaf cert:
  184db2fbca0995333804bb28f9d0cb6026978692
Full chain:
  7dd2a6cd15b069fb11faca26f40bf48b2d7197a4
------------------------------------
Verified Issuance Policies:
    1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.7
    2.23.140.1.2.1
Verified Application Policies:
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication
Cert is an End Entity certificate
Leaf certificate revocation check passed
CertUtil: -verify command completed successfully.
```

Comment: can you elaborate what do you see in the chain when looking from domain computers and non-domain computers?

Comment: I'd love to but I'm not sure what else you're looking for other than what I said.
The chain on the working test web server and the DC both show 3 tiers. Starting at the top: COMODO -> COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA -> My Cert
The chain on the non-working web server (which is part of the domain), from top down: USER Trust -> COMODO -> COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA -> My Cert

Comment: If there is something else you're specifically looking for that I didn't provide please let me know and I'll post it right away.

Comment: it was unclear from your post what chains are produced by both clients. Can you run the following command `certutil -verify sslcert.cer` against your ssl cert (replace file name in the command with an actual one) and post results from working and non-working machines? You can hide sensitive information (by replacing it with asterisks).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to security certificates and the like. How do I know which filename to put in the command? Is there a certutil command that will list the names I can reference by to run the verify command?

Comment: I have edited the post to include the responses. I just ran the command on the original cert file from the CA on both web servers.

Comment: Seems, both chains are equals.

Comment: Well they're both off the same cert file so that would make sense.
The Certification Path tab when clicking on the installed cert is what was different on the two machines.